# C memcpy to swap rows of 2D array

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am trying to use `memcpy` C library function to swap rows of 2D array(array of strings). Source files for this task is below:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main.h"

char *table[NBLOCK] = {
    "abcdefghi",
    "defghiabc",
    "ghiabcdef",
    "bcaefdhig",
    "efdhigbca",
    "higbcaefd",
    "cabfdeigh",
    "fdeighcab",
    "ighcabfde",
};

int main() {
    swap_rows(table, 0, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

**main.h**

```
#define NBLOCK 9
#define BLOCK_CELLS 9

void swap_rows(char**, int, int);
```

**shuffle.c**

```
#include <string.h>
#include "main.h"

void swap_rows(char **table, int r1, int r2) {
    char tmp[BLOCK_CELLS];
    size_t size = sizeof(char) * BLOCK_CELLS;

    memcpy(tmp, table[r1], size);
    memcpy(table[r1], table[r2], size); /* SIGSEGV here */
    memcpy(table[r2], tmp, size);
}
```

Segmentation fault occurs inside `swap_rows` function. Out of three `memcpy` calls shown above, the first one works as expected. I commented out the last two `memcpy` calls and added below line:

```
table[0][0] = 'z';
```

But, segmentation fault occurred again. Why I am not allowed to override values of `table` in `swap_rows` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowed to modify string literals.
For more information, see [c - Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a "char *s" initialized with a string literal, but not "char s[]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-char-s-initialized-with-a).

You can modify values of pointers to swap rows.

```
void swap_rows(char **table, int r1, int r2) {
    char* tmp;

    tmp = table[r1];
    table[r1] = table[r2];
    table[r2] = tmp;
}
```

If you prefer to use `memcpy()`:

```
void swap_rows(char **table, int r1, int r2) {
    char* tmp;
    size_t size = sizeof(tmp);

    memcpy(&tmp, &table[r1], size);
    memcpy(&table[r1], &table[r2], size);
    memcpy(&table[r2], &tmp, size);
}
```

Comment: Re “You are not allowed to modify string literals”: Proper phrasing is that the C standard does not define what happens when you attempt to modify string literals. The C standard does not actually prohibit trying; you are allowed to modify them, or at least to try. This distinction does not make a big difference here, but it is important to understanding the C standard in general: The C standard provides an open area where you can use defined features and also bring in your own; it is not a walled garden that you are barred from leaving.

Comment: Ok, but using `memcpy` to copy the value of a pointer to char into another pointer to char is a bit odd.

Answer (score 3):

In your code `table` is **not** defined as a 2D array of `char`, it is an array of pointers to `char` initialized with pointers to string literals, which must not be modified.

You get a segmentation fault because the string literals are stored in read-only memory protected by the operating system.

You should either swap the pointers in `swap_rows` or define `table` as a real 2D array and swap the rows with an appropriate prototype:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

//#include "main.h"
#define NBLOCK 9
#define BLOCK_CELLS 9

void swap_rows(char table[][BLOCK_CELLS], int, int);

char table[NBLOCK][BLOCK_CELLS] = {
    "abcdefghi",
    "defghiabc",
    "ghiabcdef",
    "bcaefdhig",
    "efdhigbca",
    "higbcaefd",
    "cabfdeigh",
    "fdeighcab",
    "ighcabfde",
};

int main() {
    swap_rows(table, 0, 2);
    return 0;
}

void swap_rows(char table[][BLOCK_CELLS], int r1, int r2) {
    char tmp[BLOCK_CELLS];
    size_t size = sizeof(tmp);

    memcpy(tmp, table[r1], size);
    memcpy(table[r1], table[r2], size);
    memcpy(table[r2], tmp, size);
}
```